# Heat concerns using 12/14 AWG wire for 30A 5V DC power over shorter distances?

Tags: safety, wire, led-strip, thermal, high-current

I’m hoping for some advice on wire gauges in practice with respect to heat/safety. I am planning an LED strip setup and have created the following diagram:

[image]

The setup is designed to be modular, A sections are the strips, mounted to diffusion tubes with MT60 Connectors (30A Capable) at each end, and supplementary power lines alongside the LED strips. B sections are the connecting wires (no set length for these) with matching MT60 connectors.

#### Other info/calculations:

- Each strip is 43.2W draw maximum (from manufacturers data sheet)
- So each string of 3 draws 129.6W, 25.9A @ 5V
- Max for the system is 259.2W, 25.9A
- Strips use the SK6812 Chip 3.5-5V

## Questions:

#### 1. Can I safely use 12 or 14 AWG wire for A sections?

I’ve read that the higher voltage drop generates more heat, which makes sense. I’d like to use 10 AWG wire for the B sections but the supplemental power lines need to be routed through the diffusion tubes which have limited space. I’ve done some calculations to determine how long I can make the B sections without running into voltage drop problems but I’m mostly concerned with heat/cable fires.

**10 AWG Section A**

For Section A (total 3 meters) with 10 AWG wire @ 25.9A = 0.51V drop
This means for Section B with 10 AWG that leaves 5.8m of remaining length before the voltage drops to 3.5V

**12 AWG Section A**

For Section A (total 3 meters) with 12 AWG wire @ 25.9A = 0.808V drop
This means for Section B with 10 AWG that leaves 4.1m of remaining length before the voltage drops to 3.5V

**14 AWG Section A**

For Section A (total 3 meters) with 14 AWG wire @ 25.9A = 1.284V drop
This means for Section B with 10 AWG that leaves 1.4m of remaining length before the voltage drops to 3.5V

#### 2. Is there anything to be concerned about with the data line?

From what I gather at low amps like the data signal will be, voltage drop isn’t as much of an issue and I could go pretty thin with the gauge. Are there interference issues running all of the cables together? Does the data line need to be shielded?

Comment: As I recall , you cannot run more than 10m of 5V Stripleds, so distributed  power is needed. Verify.

Comment: The total strip length in each string is only 3m. The supplemental power lines are already doing distributed power to both ends of each strip. (the red and black lines parallel to the strips are completely separate wire)

Comment: The question sounds like a design review / peer review request. It is easier to answer to clear, focused, and targeted questions than those with multiple variables. Reading [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270733/where-can-i-find-detailed-rules-and-guidelines) and sub links is suggested in order for questions get better answers.

Comment: Did you get it worked? I m trying same setup.